# How to run brick application?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack, ghci, hoogle

I need to install [bhoogle](https://github.com/andrevdm/bhoogle). I've already installed cabal by `stack install hoogle` command and I've created default database.
I don't know how to run application with the GUI. I have bhoogle repo downloaded on my Mac and  `stack ghci Setup` nor  `stack ghci App/Main` doesn't work. No GUI is being displayed. 
I think that all the requirements are satisfied, but the method of running the app is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your solution works, I don't think it's ideal, since the point of having entrypoints defined in a .cabal file is so that you can let stack do the grunt work (navigating the directories to the main `hs` file).

If you want to install `bhoogle` system-wide, as its purpose suggests, then you can `stack install bhoogle` from anywhere outside of a stack directory.

If, however, you want to compile and run it without installing it, `bhoogle` uses `make`, so you can build it with `make` and then fetch the executable from the `.stack-work` directory. Alternatively, from stack 1.9.1, you can use `stack run`, an analog to `cabal run`. For earlier versions of stack, you can use `stack build --exec bhoogle`.

Answer (score 0):

The key was to run it using the following command: `stack App/Main.hs`.